# How can I make program call from bash in Ubuntu 18.04 using software "A" name, but executing software name "B"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I did search over web but didn't find information how can I solve this one in my case. I have two software packages installed over PIP package manager, one is under development and another too, I need original call to execute forked one at this moment.

I'm not good with Linux and I was not able to find how to run in bash shell "software-original" with link to execute "software-fork" it does the same thing and all functionality is same. I have tried to make symlink, but later have understood that won't work it's not an folder or link to executable.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 TLS

Can anyone point me to right direction ?

Regards.

Comment: You could use [Bash Aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/).

Comment: Thank you @harrymc That's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

[Bash Aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)
is the bash solution to such problems.